# Go cross-platform way for IPC

Tags: go, ipc

I am writing a service (daemon) that suppose to run on both *nix and Windows. The service part will have a `xxxctl` companion program that will need to trigger actions in service and receive a feedback from it.

I have initially looked at signals, however these have 2 problems:

- they do not seem to be really cross-platform (there are platform specific caveats)
- they do not offer any way to communicate from signal recipient back to initiator (in C/C++ recipient will see which PID send signal, in Go this is not exposed unless implemented manually using cgo)

I am currently looking towards unix sockets and named pipes. Each respectively available only in their world, which means added complexity to application and dealing with that.

My question is -- other than IP sockets, is there any other option left for organizing IPC communication in cross-platform way using Go?

PS: I would like to avoid using cgo and/or IP sockets as much as possible, though do not completely reject this idea.

Comment: Though using IP sockets looks fine, how about using platform-specific way for those tiny differences for each platforms and wrap it as abstract API?

Comment: add: I know it's not cross-platform way you want, but many of libraries out there seems using this technique.

Comment: @hallazzang platform specific way on *nix is stable, but on windows (named pipes) is apparently still in alfa (or beta, that is not clear).

Comment: Since you are only triggering actions and receiving feedback. Wouldn't TCP be a simplest natural choice? Best part you can do it that across machines when you eventually need that (done securely of cause :))

Comment: @biosckon that would mean adding IP stack to the equation, which is not present in main application logic at all (not everything written in go is network related). In C/C++ world that is done via shared memory, go maintainers decided not to do shared memory there. Sigh.

Comment: Consider https://nats.io/ with its Go client https://github.com/nats-io/go-nats for cross platform communication. Or try gRPC which does not require an intermediate server https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go

Comment: @AlexandervanTrijffel please re-read the question. It is about IPC, it is a serious overkill to use Internet based services like that.

Comment: ipc as in on one single box? and the "cross platform" is only for different builds, not for interbox communication?

Comment: @RickyA IPC as in inter-process communication. That pretty much always implies two processes on a single box.